# Place div one below another using CSS flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am learning CSS flex. My HTML code is like below

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: 200px;
}

.box>*:first-child {
  align-self: stretch;
}

.box .selected {
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div class="selected">Three</div>
  <div>Four</div>
</div>
```

My output is like below

[image]

I would like to place `Three` just below `Two` and `Four` just below `Three`.

How can I do that ?

Comment: `align-self:end` or `margin-top:auto`, should do ;)

Comment: Do you need to use flex? it's way easier to achieve using css Grid

Comment: Thanks @arieljuod. Could you please show me some examples ? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know it this is what you look for (I guess you have more requirements) https://codepen.io/arieljuod/pen/qBNRMMg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set your `align-self` to `flex-end` for the last one. This is the best you can do with flexbox, because grid is better in this case. You might need to adjust the height of your `.box`

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: 120px;
}

.box>* {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.box>*:first-child {
  align-self: stretch;
}

.box .selected {
  align-self: center;
}

.box>*:last-child {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div class="selected">Three</div>
  <div>Four</div>
</div>
```

Following on from the comments, you should be using grid to make your exact result. Try using this:

```css
.box {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px;
  grid-template-rows: 50px;
  height: 120px;
}

.box>* {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  grid-column: 2;
}

.box>*:first-child {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1 / 4;
}

.box .selected {
  align-self: center;
}

.box>*:last-child {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div class="selected">Three</div>
  <div>Four</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @corn on the cob. Your solution is not working. Thanks.

Comment: It works for the first one, but not the second. Still working on that bit.

Comment: Did you get my issue ? `One` and `Two` will place side by side. `Three` will come just below `Two`. `Four` will come just below `Three`.

Comment: That's what happens in my post, isn't it?

Comment: No. I need to place `Three` just under `Two`. `Four` under `Three`. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223554/discussion-between-corn-on-the-cob-and-abu-abu).

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox works with parent and immediate child containers. Once you get beyond immediate children, you need to create a new flexbox (that is, nested flexboxes).

To make this solution very simple, just put divs 2,3,4 into a div. That way, the parent (`.box`) will have two immediate child divs to arrange side by side. Then, the new right-side container will have 3 child divs that it can style (using flex) to be stacked vertically. *(A div can be both a child flex container and a parent flex container at the same time -- see div `.rside`, and each div with the class `centerVertHoriz`)*

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  width:300px;
  min-height: 300px;
}
.rside{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

/*  For appearance only */
.lside{
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 200px;
  background: wheat;
}
.rside div{
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 90px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

/*  Center text within each div */
.centerVertHoriz{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="lside centerVertHoriz">One</div>
  <div class="rside">
    <div class="centerVertHoriz">Two</div>
    <div class="selected centerVertHoriz">Three</div>
    <div class="centerVertHoriz">Four</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### References:

[Brief, concise, video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k32voqQhODc)

[Concise flexbox cheatsheet](https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/)